# Running Ubuntu on PC- A Couple of Questions?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, performance, cpu

I am currently thinking about buying a new laptop, and I want to buy a PC for its good price to hardware ratio and run Ubuntu on it because I do a lot of app and web development work.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea?
2. How good is the performance of Ubuntu compare to native Windows 7/8
3. Will the touch screen work for Ubuntu if I were to buy a touch screen PC?
4. What is the true processor speed of the computer with Turbo Boost? Say if the computer's base processor is 2.4 GHz but it can be Turbo Boosted to 3.2 GHz, does that mean the computer's "true" CPU speed is 3.2 GHz? Will the Turbo Boost technology negatively affect the lifespan of the processor?

Comment: Since you ask at a Ubuntu site, I dare say the answer to question 1 is "yes". :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. You can dualboot Windows and Ubuntu anyway.
2. Performance is similar.
3. I don't think so. Please indicate the model you want to buy.
4. This is not a question related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Does StackExchange have a computer hardware Q&A site? I would love to ask some of my questions there.

Comment: Oh, and here's the device I'm interested in: [link](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Lenovo+-+IdeaPad+P500+Touch+15.6%26%2334%3B+Touch-Screen+Laptop+-+6GB+Memory+-+1TB+Hard+Drive+-+Gray/9130056.p?id=1218992516657&skuId=9130056#tab=specifications)